# XPATH : Use Preceding for 2 elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below structure , and I would like to know the preceding division

```
<manual>
  <body>
    <division> ..Div1..   </division>
    <division> ..Div2..   </division>
  </body>
</manual>
```

I wanted to use `count(preceding :: body/division)`, so that it will return **1** when used under `Div1` and return **2** when used under `Div2`.

But I'm not sure if we can use a syntax like body/division. Please help in achieving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `preceding` axis won't include the ancestors of the current element, so in your case `count(preceding::body)` returns zero for both divs.

Try this expression...

```
<xsl:value-of 
    select="count(ancestor::division[parent::body]|preceding::division[parent::body])" />
```

Or, if your divs are always going to be under a `division` you could just do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::division[parent::body]) + 1" />,
```